# IBAction not getting called for my textfields inside the scroll view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am having a ScrollView which is a child of a View and then several textfields as children of

this ScrollView. I am trying to give IBAction to these textfields via nib and setting the

delegates of the textfields also via nib.The delegate method of UITextField gets called

without any problem,but the IBAction for the TextField is never called. My view hierarchy is

as follows

```
 UIView -->(TopMost Level )
   |
 ScrollView-->(Child of UIView)
   |
 Several TextFields-->(children of Scrollview)
```

All the TextFields are having the same IBAction. I am working on Xcode 4.5 and working on

ARC based project. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is completely wrong. We can set IBAction to textField

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked around and found a solution my self.

I was declaring IBAction with Touch Down Event which works perfectly fine if TextField is

inside the UIView not the ScrollView.

But when the TextField is inside the ScrollView , the IBAction for the TextField should be

declared with EditingDidBeginEvent.

I don't know the reason behind it though.